# Shell script :[too many arguments

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Can somebody explain why my `if` statement is not working?

```
if [ [ $# -ge 2 ] && [ [ grep -o "$2" $1 | wc -l ] -gt 0  ] ]
```

Comment: What are the input parameters of your script?

Comment: Consider running it through [ShellCheck](https://www.shellcheck.net) to autodetect common problems

Comment: What you have posted is not a complete statement.  Is this your entire script?

Comment: i am actually passing  "sh myfile.sh input.txt pattern" , therefore in the if condition mentioned above first there will be a check if no. of arguments is greater than 2 or not , and also if pattern exist in input.txt

Comment: Why do you have random `[` and `]` in there?

Comment: Cause i don't Know the proper way

Comment: @thatotherguy thanks man it worked but other way around!

Comment: If you invoke the script via `sh`, it means that it is intended to be a POSIX Shell script and not a bash script, and you should remove the _bash_ tag from your post.

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
[ [ $# -ge 2 ] && [ [ grep -o "$2" $1 | wc -l ] -gt 0  ] ]
```

With:

```
[ $# -ge 2 ] && grep -q "$2" "$1"
```

In this command:

- `[ $# -ge 2 ]` tests to see if 2 or more parameters were provided
- `&&` is logical-and
- `grep -q "$2" "$1"` returns true if pattern `$2` appears in file `$1`.  The option `-q` tells `grep` to be quiet and just set the exit code which is what the `if` command will be looking for.

#### Example:

Consider a directory with this file:

```
$ cat input.txt
a pattern here
```

Let's set the parameters as they would be in the shell script:

```
$ set -- input.txt pattern
```

Now, let's run our command:

```
$ if [ $# -ge 2 ] && grep -oq "$2" $1; then echo yes; fi
yes
```

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out you have your brackets wrong but I'd write that code as separate tests anyway so you can provide meaningful error messages, e.g.:

```
(( $# >= 2 ))     || { printf '$# is too small\n' >&2; exit 1; }
grep -q "$2" "$1" || { printf 'grep found nothing\n' >&2; exit 1; }
```

or whatever it is you're trying to express. Whatever you're doing - keep it simple...